# Merge two Movie libraries - Software that will ignore duplicates but take higher quality of two files

Tags: comparison, file-merging, merge

I'm looking for reccomendations for either Windows or Linux, or worst case Mac, for software to combine librarys. Often people want to do a library swap, but the truth is, I don't trust most peoples librarys. They often have lower quality rips.

I'd like software that could help me with this, could be a script, but a GUI for Windows would be ideal for this task.

The software should help with the following tasks:

1. Identify Duplicates regardless of extensions, there is already FileBot File Renamer to make the names the same, except extensions (mkv/mp4/avi etc).
2. Take the better two of the duplicates of found and choose better by list of filters, IE: Resolution and/or 5.1 Audio.
3. Ignor importing non duplicates of low resolution like 480P SD garbage.

Note: This is mainly regards to movies, I can do TV shows manually generally. It doesn't necessarily need to scrap any remote DB's like TVDB. If the software can just find the info from the filename and attributes, that should be enough.

Comment: Not fully automatic but a tool that could ease you through this would be Auslogics Duplicate File Finder.  (I'm talking about the free version.  They might have a more powerful paid version that would do it all for you.)